# This or That when talking about an abstract idea?

Tags: grammar

The difference between **This** and **That**, as I understand it, is that **This** refers to something that is *here*, and **That** refers to something that is *There*.

However, when I want to talk about something that is neither here nor there, something that has more of an abstract nature, which should I use?

For example, in this (rather technical) sentence:

> ...any matching result in the `DataGridView` cells, is highlighted. To achieve ***this*/*that*** I use the `CellPainting` event...

Comment: The object of **current** reference is ***this***. Cf. **This** is my opinion, if you don't agree, **that** is your problem.

Comment: Related/ Possible Duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/4325/14666 ; https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48626/14666 ; https://english.stackexchange.com/q/35781/14666

Comment: Why can't you simply use **the result** or **it** and dispense with the problem altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule. When dealing with abstract terms, usage of this/that is contextual to how the abstract term is perceived.

> ...any matching result in the `DataGridView` cells, is highlighted. To achieve this/that I use the `CellPainting` event...

In this case, I would use "this" because it almost directly follow the thing it's referencing (the act of highlighting). However, "that" would be equally grammatically correct; although I think most people would intuitively use "this" here.