# "this way" vs "that way"

Tags: word-choice, this-that

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Using “that” and “this” interchangeably](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/using-that-and-this-interchangeably)

When should I use "this way" or "that way"? Is there any difference between these two when they used in a sentences? More specifically do these two sentences mean the same thing:

> Don't look at me this way!
>
> Don't look at me that way!

As far as I understand, someone should use "this way" when he is intended to mean something very specific to the situation. Say when you point to some bad picture and say to the students, "Don't do it this way!".

#### Update 1

I have looked the answers to the question [Using “that” and “this” interchangeably](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/using-that-and-this-interchangeably), but this makes things even more difficult. It seems I should use "Don't look at me this way" sentence. Google thinks so (15,600,000 for "Don't look at me this way" vs 5,190,000 for "Don't look at me that way"). But there is a song named "Don't Look At Me That Way" by Chaka Khan after all!

#### Update 2

Please note that "this way" ≠ "this" + "way". It has much deeper meaning. Aristotle said that the whole is more than the sum of its parts. So I guess there is no need to close this question only because you think other way, really!

Comment: Pray tell, what does "this way" mean, if not "this way"?

Comment: Well, when translated to Russian it has a meaning of "so", "as", "thus", "like that", "in a same sense", "here", "there" and may have other meanings. The whole is more than the sum of its parts, Aristotle.

Comment: For your specific example, I'd say "Don't look at me like that"; which resolves your problem, but doesn't answer your question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely "that way." You're referring to something away from yourself (the way the other person is looking at you). Google hit counts are a poor measure of anything.