# Using "this" or "that" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, british-english, sentence, dialogue

I wondered which term for the below paragraph is correct grammar and whether I should use "this" or "that".

> Peter kept wondering about everything he had overheard. For the time being, he wanted to appear as busy as possible until he knew all the facts. **That**/**This** way, his aunt and uncle would leave him alone – giving him time to think up a plan.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using 'that' and 'this' interchangeably](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/using-that-and-this-interchangeably) Or this? ['this way' vs 'that way'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94225/this-way-vs-that-way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the explanation from Collins Cobuild
:  You can use that way or this way to refer to an action or situation that you have just mentioned, when you go on to mention the likely consequence or effect of it.
Keep the soil moist. That way, the seedling will flourish. 
I am left holding the baby; but at least this way I know that she's being well looked after.