# A question on anaphoric and cataphoric references

Tags: word-choice

Is it 'this' or 'that' that conveys **an anaphoric reference?** 
I want to refer back to "that I wrote critical and analytical essays".

> It is true that I wrote critical and analytical essays on a regular
>   basis; **that**, however, did not satisfy my academic eagerness.

or?

> It is true that I wrote critical and analytical essays on a regular
>   basis; **this**, however, did not satisfy my academic eagerness.

Comment: Either word is possible, but *this* is better. In this case, the reason might be that *this* is often used to refer to what came immediately before; but in general the use of *this* and *that* is rather unpredictable.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/4325/14666 http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100817/when-to-use-this-and-when-to-use-that

Answer (score 1):

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* in its section (p1506) on anaphoric uses of *this* and *that* with noun phrases as antecedents states:

> ... both *this* and *that* can be used anaphorically - and in general one
>   could be replaced by the other with very little effect on the meaning.

In contrast, Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p591) does detect a slight difference:

> *This* is preferred when there is more to say about the new subject of
>   discussion:
>
> "Then in 1917 he met Andrew Lewis. This was a turning point in his
>   career: the two men entered into a partnership that lasted until 1946,
>   and ..."
>
> (More natural than ... "That was a turning point ...")

It is likely that the OP's sentence will be followed by something more on the new subject (*academic eagerness*). For example:

> It is true that I wrote critical and analytical essays on a regular
>   basis; this, however, did not satisfy my academic eagerness. I also
>   engaged in research ... etc.

Thus if we follow Swan, *this* is to be preferred to *that* in the context of the OP's sentence.

*This*, as the more present or proximal pronoun, may also better convey the sense that what is being referred to is relevant in the present context (for example, an application letter or cv). So, in the context I have assumed for the OP I would use *this*.

Comment: Does Swann say **why** it is to be preferred? And by whom it is to be preferred? Sounds like Swann alone. In general, which would you prefer for a position on evolution, or nuclear physics, or geology, or grammar: a firm opinion based on personal prejudice, or an unquestioned fact stated in a standard reference work?

Comment: @JohnLawler. My answer offers an extract from the current gold standard in reference grammars (CGEL) and a very good prescriptive grammar for English language learners (Swan). I have also attempted to justify my slight personal preference for _this_ in the context in which I assume the OP will be using the sentence. The OP and other viewers will presumably decide if my answer is helpful or not. If there is another standard reference with unquestioned facts about this particular usage it would be useful to know what it is.

Comment: I see. Then, since Swann's book is for non-native speakers, he must prefer for them to speak by rules that are different from the ones that native speakers use, which are what Huddleston and Pullum report. A strange situation, indeed.

Comment: H&P state that "in general" _this_ could be replaced by _that_  with "very little effect on the meaning". Perhaps Swan has identified a particular context where there is "a non-negligible effect on the meaning". I found it interesting that Swan provided a possible explanation for my intuitive slight preference for _this_ in OP's context.

Comment: Even better, a firm opinion based on a personal prejudice that matches one's own. What could be a better source of authority?

Comment: Perhaps you missed the hedging in my answer and comment: "_Thus if we follow Swan ..._" and "_a possible explanation_" for my slight preference.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that *this* is used in cataphoric reference and *that* hardly ever; but they are also both widely used in anaphor, the basic difference then being that *this* is proximal, *that* distal.

In practice, however, unless there are two likely referents to distinguish between, they are pretty much interchangeable in anaphor.