# Demonstrative Pronouns: This/That – Advanced Usage

Tags: pronouns, demonstratives

When you learn about demonstrative pronouns, it seems like a really simple concept. This/these for nearby (physically, or with regards to time), that/those for distant things. Anywhere you go, online language sites, or Youtube, this is where the story ends mostly. But it seems to miss out on the trickier usage of demonstrative pronouns. I can't figure this out:

**Here's a sentence:**

> *Next week may change the rest of your life. And I don't say **that/this** lightly.*

What would you pick? **This**, or **that**?

I picked "this", and it was incorrect, apparently. "That" seems to be correct, as in:

> *And I don't say **that** lightly.*

What's the rule here, are we still talking demonstrative pronoun, near/distant?

**Same as in this:**

> *Check out **this/that** Youtube video: (LINK). What do you think of **this/that**?*

The near/distant trick, either in time of physical distance, doesn't really help. Suggestions?

Now, [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/using-that-and-this-interchangeably) offers some guidance:

> For a concept or idea introduced a few sentences before, I think the
>   key thing is whether it was introduced by you or the person you're
>   talking to. If you introduced it, you're "holding" the idea - use
>   "this". If they introduced it, they're "holding" it - use "that"."

But really, how does it apply here? Do I hold up my previous sentence? I think so – so **this** should be correct, am I wrong?

Disclaimer: I'm not a native speaker, but my literary agent is (a seasoned writer). He suggested **this** was incorrect, and **that** is correct.

Comment: The last two examples are run of the mill, see the linked question. Nothing advanced here. And for the first example, please specify who told you it was not correct, and what their reasoning was. "I don't say this lightly" is perfectly grammatical and perfectly idiomatic English.

Comment: my seasoned literary agent said that in his corrections ... I'm not a native speaker, he is (UK).

EDIT: taken from your linked answer: _"For a concept or idea introduced a few sentences before, I think the key thing is whether it was introduced by you or the person you're talking to. If you introduced it, you're "holding" the idea - use "this". If they introduced it, they're "holding" it - use "that"."_ -- so I would say, **this** is the correct word. I just referred to my own sentence.

Comment: Also, the runner up answer on the linked duplicate addresses the problem perfectly (by Anderson Silva). Unfortunately, nobody weighed in on his findings, so it's hard to judge its validity.

Comment: For the youtube example, where the link is given following the this/that choice, I think it has to be "this".  I'd say "This example, which I am about to give, shows ...", but never "that example", when the example hasn't yet been given.