# Difference between "Is that ok?" vs. "Is this ok?"

Tags: differences

what's the difference between this two questions?
Also, are these questions grammatically correct?

Comment: The first asks about *that* while the second asks about *this*.

Comment: Non-English speakers are always making mistakes with this in English. I really don't think my answer merited a downvote. People are so cranky here. I did go some way to explaining the difference.

Comment: @Lambie - I will note that your editing is pretty sloppy (even by my standards).

Comment: @Lambie Superficially, this is a concept that children of ten should have mastered. ELU is not intended for such basic questions. Providing answers encourages more of the same. // If the deeper problem of referencing deixis _is_ really being asked here, it becomes a duplicate of [using 'that' and 'this' interchangeably](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/using-that-and-this-interchangeably).

Comment: Actually, French speakers make this mistake all the time. They confuse this and that in English. So, it may be a basic question for English-speaking children of ten, but not adults learning English. That said, it should be in ELL, I think. I just whipped off an answer, without thinking about that. I guess I should do penance at the altar of the language gods.

Answer (score 1):

This question is about deixis, specifically, about the use of the pronouns this or that used to establish a relationship between speakers in time or space or between a speaker and a thing. 
Here is the Wikepedia take on it:[enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis)

In English, the pronouns this and that are used to establish a relationship with a thing (in reality) or with a thing or idea or series of comments in language.

Both "Is this OK?" and "Is that OK?" are fine. However, they can be used under varying circumstances.

For example, if you are doing work for me,  you can place something in front of me (a text or computer screen with information  you have created) and say: "Is this OK?" In this case, the "this" refers to the text (on paper) or the work presented by you to me on a sheet or paper or on the screen. And I can respond: "Yes, that's [the thing you have just given me] OK". I can also pick up the sheet, and say: "Yes, this [thing I now have in my hands or in front of me] is OK".

However, if you and I are discussing a problem or issue, and you come up with your ideas to resolve them, you might say: "Is that Ok?" [in reference to your own idea offered to me] and there the "that" refers to what you have just said or presented. Here, I would say to you also: Yes, that's OK [referring to what you offered]. This would not be used here in speech to refer to earlier speech.

In reference to a series of thoughts or ideas when two people or more are talking, in general, one uses THAT, in reference to  one's own speech or in reference to what another person says. However, in writing, if you write me an email and want an opinion on  some paragraph, you could write underneath it: Is this OK? It refers to what you have just expressed in writing.

This is not the entire story here but it should clear up some of your doubts.