# What's the difference between "This being the case," and "That being the case,"?

Tags: american-english, writing

Are they both correct? What's the difference between these two expressions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/using-that-and-this-interchangeably

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "that" and "this" interchangeably](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/using-that-and-this-interchangeably)